# Do I need to press Save in Titan Quest?

Tags: titan-quest

I just bought Titan Quest: Immortal Throne and am playing in strictly 2-player LAN games with my wife.

I noticed that when I press ESC, there is a button for "Save."  But if my experience with other Diablo-like games is any indication, I shouldn't actually *need* to save.  So... what's the point of that button?

Questions:

- Do I actually need to press Save before pressing Exit to Main Menu in order to save my progress?  I don't want to lose progress!
- I'm hosting.  Does my wife need to press Save?  If so, I'll need to remind her!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The save button is *not* useless. In *Titan Quest*, your game is saved whenever you find one of the fountains and save at it. But you can update your quest status and other such details in the current save by using the "Save" button as you play before you reach the next fountain.

So, for example, let's say you find a fountain, and it saves your progress. You might then continue playing for a while, find a couple of cool new items and maybe complete a quest, but you don't have time to find the next fountain before you quit. If you just quit, you'll lose those new items and the quest progress. If you save the game before you quit, your items and quest progress and what not will be saved.

Either way, the next time you load your game you'll find yourself at the last fountain at which you saved. But by using the save button you can hang onto items and quest progress.

In response to the comments, let me add the network details as well through an edit. If you're playing a network game of Titan Quest, you're only saving your own game. The host determines which quests are available in the first place, so if he's already completed stuff you haven't, you won't be able to do it.

But when the host saves his game, it saves only the status of quests, items, etc. for *his* character. When you use fountains, it saves quests, items, and respawn point for your character, and when you use the save button it saves quests and items for your character. So you should still use the save button when exiting a multi-player game as well.

Comment: In a network game, if one person saves does it save for everyone?

Comment: Ah. I suppose I never noticed because I always quit at a fountain.

Comment: This answer is blatantly wrong. Just pressing "exit game" also saves everything.

Comment: @Arperum: Anniversary Edition may have changed things.

Comment: @user598527 I've played *a lot* of the original way before the anniversary existed. I *never* used the save function. I've quit the game at all sorts of points. I never lost progress due to that. The closest I've got was the anniversary edition crashing on me and my just-assigned skillpoints being unassigned again. Even though I kept every single item I had found. And map was still explored. And that was by exiting through a crash, not through the exit to main menu button.

Comment: @Arperum: I think he missed that the game saves on exit, it's possible he forces the game to close for example (`Alt + F4`).

Answer (score 1):

Thats not true. It auto saves everything, If I quit at any moment, it will restore me to the previous fountain but with the items and experience picked up. Try it. Youll even notice your map is explored past the fountain next time.

Answer (score -2):

But you lose the *progress* that you made in that quest--all the demons, evil dead, etc. that you have killed will have come back to life the next time you open the game.  THAT is frustrating as hell.  I don't always have hours to play to make it to the next fountain.